# Why is the "reaction force" here the vector sum of the normal force and friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

[image]

(From: Class 11 NCERT Physics, Chapter 7)
*Edit: The original question:

> A 3m long ladder weighing
> 20 kg leans on a frictionless wall. Its feet
> rest on the floor 1 m from the wall as shown
> in Fig.7.27. Find the reaction forces of the
> wall and the floor.

The example question asks to find the "reaction forces of the wall and the floor" for which they have labelled $\mathbf{F_2}$ and $\mathbf{F_1}$. I have no problem in the general steps to solving the question in its entirety, however,

> why $\mathbf{F_2}$ and not $\mathbf{N}$ for the "reaction force of the floor"?

I am reading the question as "what is the force **of** the floor **on** the rod at their contact point?" I believe that the friction does not contribute to that "reaction force" because there was nothing done **to** the floor to cause the reaction of static friction on the rod. 
Just to emphasize, my problem is just knowing which force the book wants me to solve for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sketch is no entirely clear without more context. But I guess the tilted line is a rod leaning on a wall?

At the contact point between rod and floor, there is indeed a normal force upwards preventing the rod from breaking through the floor.

But there also must be a friction force sideways. If there wasn't then the rod would have slipped sideways and fallen down. Since it doesn't, then we know that a friction force *is* present as a reaction to just like the normal force.

Comment: I've added the original question for more context. This a torque/principles of moments question. But I think I get it now; I was not labeling static friction as a reaction to impending motion.

Answer (score 0):

The statement of the question is ambiguous.  It could be looking for either:  the separate reaction forces at both $A$ and $B$ (four forces), or  the net reaction force at $A$ and $B$ (two forces).   I have *never* seen a reference to "net reaction force", yet  that could be what the question is after.  The fact that $F_2$ is perpendicular to the wall while $F_1$ is not is peculiar.  And the normal force at $B$ is not shown at all. The most reasonable interpretation in my opinion is that four forces are wanted.   All this goes to say that the question is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

The normal and friction forces are the components of a single reaction force from the floor.